# Websocket example won't work

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I try run this example:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class ChatServer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServer.class.getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New connection with client: {0}", 
                session.getId());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New message from Client [{0}]: {1}", 
                new Object[] {session.getId(), message});
        return "Server received [" + message + "]";
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Close connection for client: {0}", 
                session.getId());
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable exception, Session session) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Error for client: {0}", session.getId());
    }
}
```

I use `Tomcat 7.0.47`, I check link: `ws://localhost/Tests/chat`.
Do I need register this websocket or add some things in `web.xml`?
Any idea why is not working for me?

Comment: any stack trace/produced error message in server log file? What does browser produce when you are trying to connect? (Assuming that you are using browser as a client..)

Comment: There is nothing in server log, it looks like request doesn't reach server. For testing I use Chrome app 'Advanced Rest Client'.

Comment: Can you try something else? "Advanced Rest Client" does not support WebSocket connections (I don't see that in their description). Something simple as http://www.websocket.org/echo.html should work. You can also open JavaScript error console, where is usually indicated what is wrong (404, 500, other reason..)

Comment: Same result. I get message: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/Tests/chat' failed: Unexpected response code: 404. It's something wrong with server side. Mayby I need another class or something?

Comment: Why `ws://localhost/Tests/chat` and not `ws://localhost/ChatServer/chat`?

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem trying to use WebSocket API on Tomcat 7.0.47. The error message being displayed client side wasn't any help at all and my server side endpoint was never being created.

After much wasted time I found it was due to way I had set the dependency for `javax.websocket-api`. I'm using Maven which has the default scope as `compile` which causes problems as Tomcat has the `websocket-api.jar` in its lib folder. Setting the dependency to `provided` solved it.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this helps

It's also worth noting that if running behind Apache you will need `mod_proxy_wstunnel` and if using IIS you will need version 8.0 as anything prior does not support websockets.

Comment: Really thank you bro.. I spent more than 4 hours to find this thing

Comment: I had the reverse problem here: I put the dependency in provided early one but the rest of the coordinates were wrong. Fun fact, `<groupId>javax</groupId>  <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>` also compiles but doesn't work. 5 hours lost...

Comment: Thank you for this!  Add 4 hours to everyone else's lost time.  Also to add, if you use Tomcat 8, it works without having to specify `provided`.

Comment: How does it work with travis? My travis builds are failiing with scope provided.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal This is pretty old now. If you're using Tomcat 8 or 9 (or even later versions of 7) it's not required. Also, this is standard maven stuff. Using travis-ci does not make a difference

Comment: So if I upgrade to tomcat 8, I wont even have to include this in my pom.xml? And if I have to, then can you please help me out with this question I posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490788/travis-build-with-scope-provided-java-websockets

Comment: This is not working for me, any ideas why? I tried it with tomcat 7.0.96, It still gives me 404 during handshake

Comment: @d_void that's a different problem and should be another question with further detail of what code you have and what you have tried to resolve your problem.