# Travis build with scope provided (java websockets)

Tags: java, maven, servlets, travis-ci

I am setting up websockets with my Java j2ee servlet application. I was able to write the entire code and got the websockets working using following maven configuration -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My implementation does not work without `<scope>provided</scope>` and gives `handshake exception: 404 not found`.

Now, when I deploy my application on dev machines using travis, it gives exception while creating a build, and throws Java exception that `ServerEndpoint class not found`. I am assuming that it is because since scope is provided, Travis is not downloading the required jars while building a build on travis.

How do I avoid this, and ensure that we are able to work on local as well as deploy our builds via travis.

Comment: I find it unlikely that Travis implements its own Maven instead of just running the one that already exists.

Comment: @JFMeier Sorry, I did not get you. Can you please explain a bit more. I am assuming that Travis will try to rebuild the war using my pom.xml and will download all the required jars. Maybe it is skipping the jar with scope provided. Thanks.

Comment: You build the war with Maven, right? So Travis will also build it with Maven. And it is unlikely that Travis has a Maven that behaves fundamentally different. What may be the case is that Travis uses a different `settings.xml`, so e.g. contacts other repositories.

Comment: Got it. Maybe my local also has tomcat installation which already contains websockets, but it is not on travis side. So it is not giving me an error on local, but on travis.

Comment: The question is about the build but the description is a runtime issue. Which servlet container is being used and the version would be good information to include. Is the websocket api jar provided by your container?

Comment: The error is a compile time error thrown while building a build in travis.